# How to structure query to display different versions of one column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble structuring a query to display three different columns as versions of text contained within one column-specifically, an "Upper-case" column, a "lower-case" column and a "Mixed-case" column.  I've created the following query intending to concatenate via `CONCAT` or `||` but I'm open to alternatives.  Here is my attempt in process:

```
SELECT city,
       UPPER(city) AS "Upper-case",
       lower(city) AS "lower-case",
       city AS "MIXED-case"
FROM student.zipcode;
```

The above satisfies my query but is there a more elegant solution?  I'd appreciate any other alternatives.  Thank you!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this query. You might consider using `InitCap()` function instead of the `Upper(SUBSTR())`, but besides that, this seems like a very reasonable query.

Comment: Nothing wrong, but why you `SUBSTR(city,1,29)` before upper?

Comment: Thank you @JNevill!  @JuanCarlosOropeza, my original solution excluded `substr`; I only included as a work-in-progress.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to print the same string in upper/lower/mixed case you don't need to substring. Also... "city" is repeated two times in your query.

I would change it this way:

```
SELECT 
   city AS "Original",
   upper(city) AS "Upper",
   lower(city) AS "Lower"
FROM student.zipcode;
```

Comment: as a DBA n00b, my attempt seemed all too easy; I appreciate your response as a vote for confidence :D  Thank you.